# Formatting strings in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

i have a dataframe

| Name |
| --- |
| Joe Smith |
| Jane Doe |
| Homer Simpson |

i am trying to format this to get to

| Name |
| --- |
| Smith, Joe |
| Doe, Jane |
| Simpson, Homer |

i have this code, and it works for ~ 80% of users in my list but some users are not coming through right.

```
invalid_users = ['Test User', 'Test User2', 'Test User3']


for index, row in df_Users.iterrows():
    gap_pos = df_Users["Name"][index].find(" ") 
    if gap_pos > 0 and row["Name"] not in invalid_users:
        row["Name"] = df_Users["Name"][index][len(df_Users["Name"][index])-gap_pos+1:].strip() +', ' + df_Users["Name"][index][:gap_pos]
```

the users who are not coming through correctly, usually their last name is truncated somewhere - i.e. Simpson ==> mpson

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: See [Using Regex to change the name values format in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68446291/using-regex-to-change-the-name-values-format-in-a-dataframe/68447207?noredirect=1#comment121012184_68447207)

Comment: if you still want this loop, use `split` instead, `"Joe Smith".split(" ")` will give you a list like this `['Joe', 'Smith']`

Comment: Why `[len(df_Users["Name"][index])-gap_pos+1:]`? A simple `[gap_pos+1:]` should do (but better use one of the mentioned alternatives anyway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just split on space, then reverse it (that's what `.str[::-1]` is doing) and join on `,` :

```py
>>> df['Name'].str.split(' ').str[::-1].str.join(', ')
0        Smith, Joe
1         Doe, Jane
2    Simpson, Homer
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

And if your data contains the name like `Jr. Joe Smith`, then you may do it following way:

```py
df['Name'].str.split(' ').str[::-1].apply(lambda x:(x[0],' '.join(x[1:]))).str.join(', ')
```

Comment: you got the first and last name flipped

Comment: Yes, but you're not putting the last name first.

Comment: I like this answer better, but it's worth pointing out that "Jill St. John" would become "John, St., Jill", which is not desired.  Still, I think this gives the right skeleton.  It depends on what his data looks like.

Comment: Yes sir, you are right @TimRoberts, it depends on the data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you were trying to with `len` there, but it's not right.  You just want to start straight from `gap_pos`:

```py
row["Name"] = df_Users["Name"][index][gap_pos+1:].strip() +', ' + df_Users["Name"][index][:gap_pos]
```

I would be tempted to use `split` for this.

Answer (score -1):

Pandas is a library that takes profit of vectorial operations, especially for simple transformations and most of DataFrame manipulations.

Given your example, here is a code that would work:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"name": ["Joe Smith", "Jane Doe", "Homer Simpson"]})
# df
#              name
# 0       Joe Smith
# 1        Jane Doe
# 2   Homer Simpson

df["name"] = df["name"].apply(lambda x: f"{x.split(' ')[1]}, {x.split(' ')[0]}")
# df
#               name
# 0       Smith, Joe
# 1        Doe, Jane
# 2   Simpson, Homer
```

The `apply` function takes every row and applies the specified function to each one of them.
Here, the specified function is a `lambda` function that, supposing the name pattern is "FirstName LastName", does what you want.